# After Windows 10 upgrade, going into lock screen (Windows + L) sometimes results in unresponsive black screen with only mouse cursor visible

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, lock-screen, mouse-cursor, unresponsive

Upgrade was successful and system generally works fine with Windows 10. There are a number of similar issues on the web but not exactly the same.

- This happens after pressing Windows + L to go into the lock screen
- It doesn't happen every time, I'm not sure what the pattern is
- No warnings in device manager
- Pressing Ctrl and entering password doesn't work (as recommended in several places)
- Windows + P as recommended in other sites does nothing, Windows + Ctrl + B beeped but otherwise did nothing
- Ctrl + Alt + Delete does nothing obvious, Ctrl + Shift + Esc also nothing
- Mouse cursor does not respond
- Num lock light on keyboard still responds at least at first, however I also observed it stopping responding
- Pressing power button to sleep does seem to sleep (external monitor powers off), but pressing it again to reawaken returns to black screen
- Music playing in Chrome continued playing in background

The only way I've found to address this is by restarting the machine, which takes a long time. This is on an HP laptop, I have two external monitors, one is connected via a DisplayLink USB to video converter.

As there is no pattern I would have to try any suggestions next time I see it so there may be a delay.